# the future-existence of a currently "nonexisted" object

Tags: word-choice

I'm trying to convey the idea of the existence of a determined future object that does not yet exist.

In other words,

> the **future existence** of a currently non-existing object.

I don't think simply using the word existence for it is right since for now the object does not exist. It is only coming into existence in the future.

So is there a more technical term to express the **future existence** (or "coming-existence") of a currently non-existing object?

Comment: I would say "future existence" (no need for a hyphen) and "non-existing".

Comment: @PeterShor yeah I think the hyphen is unnecessary too since it is just an adjetive and a noun. Thanks for the reminder. I should correct it.

Comment: The phrase _non-existed_ isn’t very English-sounding.  Maybe you want _nonexistent_ or _non-existing_?

Comment: @DanielHarbour yeah definitely. Using the not very English-sounding word _non-existed_ makes it looks like I'm emphasizing the nonexistence **in the past** and that's never my intention.

Comment: .........future (the dots are merely to make the comment possible)

Comment: *"If this is the future; where is my jetpack?"*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***e·mer·gence*** /iˈmərjəns/ *emergences*, plural (Google)
Noun
The process of coming into being, or of becoming important or prominent.
- *the emergence of the environmental movement*
- *Japan's emergence as a modern state*

... come into existence. (AHD-IV,2000)
come into existence; take on form or shape; (WordNet 3.0)

Comment: A solid choice.  You could qualify it with "impending" or "eventual" to indicate that it's coming sooner or later.

Comment: @Hellion Yes, depending on how *future* is qualified in OP's context. *Gradual*, *eventual*, *impending*, *strategic* ... all might be possible.

Answer (score -1):

A suitable "everyday" word would be *creation*, for example.

More technical terms include *instantiation, incarnation, embodiment, actualisation, reification*, etc.